# bootstrap modal interaction with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

help me please to solve my problem!
I have a page with a boostrap3 modal with the form inside. "Save" button in this modal is sending AJAX-query, if it's successful, I trigger "hide" event for my modal, like this:

```
success: function (data) {
            PERSON_AJAX.updatePersonsTable(data);
            $('#custom-width-modal-person').modal('hide');
            $('#person-created-alert').modal('show');
        },
```

I also check my form to be changed, I serialize form on open event, then check if it equals to the serialized form on hide event (when user closes modal without clicking "save"), ask user if he wants to save changes, if it's true I manually call my "save" function like this:

```
form_serialize: function(){
    $("#custom-width-modal-person").on({
        'shown.bs.modal': function(){
            MODAL_BEHAVIORS.formData = $('#create-person').serialize();
        },
        'hide.bs.modal': function(e){
            if ( MODAL_BEHAVIORS.formData !== $('#create-person').serialize() ){
                if(confirm("Do you want to save the data?")){
                    PERSON_AJAX.setPerson();
                }
            }
        },
    });

},
```

The problem here is that setPerson() method also contains hide.bs.modal event and when user wants to save data by just closing the modal the function calls twice. How can I prevent this interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do this check in hide.bs.modal.
Leave the modal hide event handler emtpy. Put this logic into a separate function:

```
function closeModal(){
    if ( MODAL_BEHAVIORS.formData !== $('#create-person').serialize() ){
        if(confirm("Do you want to save the data?")){
            PERSON_AJAX.setPerson();
        }
        else{
            $('#custom-width-modal-person').modal('hide');
        }
    }
}
```

Call `closeModal()` when the user clicks on X, presses escape, or whenever you want the modal to close.

Comment: modal should be visible until AJAX in serPerson() returns success

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if this worked :)

Comment: yes, your answer helped me alot, I restricted closing modal with ESC and clicks outside the modal, added closeModal() on click X button and added "else" statements to closeModal(). Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help ;)